# angular 2 routerLink with route params only works as a string

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a route with params defined as
`export const jobDetailsRoute: Route = {
    path: 'job-detail/:jobId/:jobTitle',
    component: JobDetailsComponent,
};`

which i import into my component like this
`public readonly jobDetailsRoute: Route = jobDetailsRoute;`

however when I reference the route as below it generates an invalid link
`http://mydomain/job-detail/%3AjobId/%3AjobTitle/oNPj5fwK/Dynamics%20365%20Developer`

`<a [routerLink]="[ jobDetailsRoute.path, job.id, job.title ]"
    [translate]="'DASHBOARD.ANCHOR'"></a>`

which throws the following error in the console
**Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'job-detail/%3AjobId/%3AjobTitle/oNPj5fwK/Dynamics%20365%20Developer'**

and when I generate the routerLink as a string I get a correct link `http://mydomain:4200/job-detail/oNPj5fwK/Dynamics%20365%20Developer`

`<a [routerLink]="[ 'job-detail', job.id, job.title ]"
    [translate]="'DASHBOARD.ANCHOR'"></a>`

any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `routerLink` expects the path segments.
So, in the first case when you use the `jobDetailsRoute.path`, the whole route with the dynamic segments are concatenated to generate the full route.

> For instance ['/team', teamId, 'user', userName, {details: true}] means that we want to generate a link to /team/11/user/bob;details=true.

[Source](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#description%22Source%22)

Comment: thank you for replying ankit, so there is no way around this? ideally I'd like to avoid having to hard code the route string everywhere in the app's templates...

Comment: AFAIK, no. And won't you be unnecessarily creating dependencies across angular modules just to reference routes.